# XCode 4.2 Debugger Issue: Showing incorrect values + addresses for pointers

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I've taken a screenshot of the compiler inconsistencies that I have been getting when creating new ViewControllers in my current project.

In this example, the debugger shows a different value for my variables 'kim', 'fakekim', and 'blah' from my log output (which shows the correct values). The debugger consistently shows the **next** instance variable obtaining the current instance variable's value ('fakekim' is assigned the value that 'kim' is supposed to have).

The issue seems to be project-specific. I've been able to reproduce the issue by importing my project on another Mac. However, if I create a new project, the debugger works fine. Was hoping to figure out the issue to prevent this from happening in the future.

Thanks for your help, StackOverflow community!

Edit: Larger screenshot image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVroE.png

[image: Debugger issue selected in red]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you change your `int`s to `NSInteger`s, do you have a better outcome?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same issue. Except with objects (vs. primitive types), the debugger shows the next pointer pointing to the current object (fakeKim would be pointing at kim's actual reference object)

Comment: I tried your experiment myself and do not get the same results. The values are being shown correctly. Are you doing anything in your -(int) methods that might alter the values being shown above? Maybe you are somehow modifying the getters for these fields that are confusing the debugger?

Comment: @ScanPlayGames: Thanks for taking the time to attempt to reproduce the issue. The error seems to be a project-specific error; I've also reproduced the issue importing my project to another Mac. But if I create a new project and add the classes, I do not get this issue.

Was hoping to figure it out to prevent this from happening again in the future.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is the symbol table somehow got screwed up. When you imported, was the build directory empty on the other Mac?

Comment: @Derrick: I don't believe so. Also, to add more info to the situation, my partner and I are working on the project together and are pushing/merging our changes from github (including any changes related to the xcodeproj folder)

Comment: When in doubt, clean xcode, close it and reopen it. Sometimes it becomes haunted with evil XCode ghosts.

Comment: Ohhhhhh. The Xcode project has a .pbxuser and pbxworkspace folder (or file, I can't remember) somewhere in there is where breakpoints are stored. That's another potential problem. If you init the hit repo from xcode, it will do the right thing, by not adding certain parts to the fit repo. There's also a way that it adds it. Some files should be treated as binary, even though they you can read them with a text editor. I forget the details, this might not help your problem, but it's good to know anyway.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, Derrick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a (very annoying) bug with LLDB in Xcode 4.3. It has been fixed in 4.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an Xcode bug.  Try dragging the .xcuserstate file from you working project to your real one, and see whether that fixes it.

You could also try a clean build (shift-command-k).